# Copying data from one Dataframe to another empty Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with some data as below:

```
cust_name, cust_id
Kevin, 101
Scott, 102
Mark, 103
Peter, 104
```

I have another empty dataframe with the below columns:

```
id, cust_name, address, profile_name, cust_id
```

I am trying to have data from the first dataframe copied to this empty Dataframe such that

```
df2['cust_name'] = df1['cust_name'] and df2['cust_id'] = df1['cust_id']
```

In the above I am calling first Dataframe as df1 and the second Dataframe as df2

Comment: why do you want to copy the data over to an empty frame? Why not just add the new columns to the current frame?

Comment: @Yo_Chris, df2 is how my end table looks like.. I am trying to have my output table structure defined in df2 and then populate fields that come from df1 and then push df2 back to the table and hence this approach

Comment: @Yo_Chris the target table has 100+ columns and that could change in future.. So df2 is basically a empty template of this table.. This way I can ensure the structure of df2 and final table are always the same.. Just that these 2 fields that I am trying to populate from df1 gets fed to this df2..

Comment: OK, are you looking to update column names that are the same or can they be different?

Comment: @Yo_Chris, column names can differ. I can manage that part..

Comment: What was wrong with your current approach: `df2['cust_name'] = df1['cust_name']`